# Vb6 dll is not able to load a c# dll

Tags: c#, vb6, interop

I have a VB6 dll and c# dll .I am calling c# dll from vb6 dll using regfree activation.
I have created two sample projects a vb6 exe and c# exe ,created manifest file for both exe and the content of the manifest is same(except name of exe.).Embeded manifest for respective exe .Now the problem is I am able to call c# dll using vb6 dll when i use vb6 sample project(VB6 exe), but same is not happening if i use c# sample project(C# exe) .

Comment: The error shown is "Automation error the system can find the file specified."

Comment: EXE files generated by a C# project already have a manifest, embedded in the EXE file.  That's the one Windows finds first, it will not use your .manifest file.  You need to alter the embedded one.  Project + Add New Item, pick the Application Manifest File template and insert your entries.

Comment: Are you sure the .exe is running as a 32-bit process?